# Quicktime file not emailing from mac to PC correctly?

Tags: macos, quicktime, pc

Someone is trying to email me a Quicktime file from their Mac to my Windows PC.   (This is audio for a presentation.)   They swear that the file contains audio and video on their end, but when I get it, the file is only 14KB in size and plays as 25 seconds of blank screen and silent audio.   The Properties in the QT player show that the file should be 67MB.

Does anyone know what the problem is here?   If the file is too huge, I would expect that nothing would transfer - instead I'm getting this weird 14KB "audio.mov" file.   He's tried it twice - I even sent the 14KB file back to him and he insists it plays fine.

I'm mystified - I don't want to press the person doing this for me too hard, because they're doing me a favor (an unpaid favor at that) and I would like this to be as easy as possible on them.    But if anybody knows "oh, the problem is ______" and how to fix it, that would be great.

UPDATE:  We also tried transferring the file over Dropbox, but I got the same 14KB file  as before.

Comment: using the Dropbox clearly shows that the SENDER is only sending 14k file.So the 14K send is only a link to the actual file, that is why it plays when you send it back.

Comment: Ah.  So if I understand correctly, it's like sending a Windows "Shortcut" instead of the actual file?  (Sorry, I'm a PC person.)

Comment: That is exactly what I think is your other side sending. Why would you otherwise see only 14K on the Dropbox? Dropbox does no filtering, it would show the full file size.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 applications on Mac called Quick Time Player.

One is the `Quick Time player` (without the 7),

The other is the `Quick Time Player 7`.This one is only basic and can be upgraded to Pro version at cost.

You should be using the QT player (without the 7) to send file via email.

To do that open the file in QT player and click on File - Sharing - Email.

If the file is to big to be sent by email use Dropbox then upload the file there (as you have done already), but make sure you are uploading the correct file. If it is audio it will be at least 5 meg or more (certainly not 14k).

Comment: Thanks, I will relay this information to the person trying to send me this file.   Hopefully this will help him!